# SprintBoot kafka value-serializer

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, jsonserializer

I have a SpringBoot project with apache kafka ( an open-source stream-processing software )
I have this listener

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "test")
public String consume(Hostel hostel) throws IOException {
}
```

this serializer

```
public class HostelSerializer implements Deserializer<Hostel> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public InputRequestMessageSerializer(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> map, boolean b) {
        this.configure(map,b);
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public Hostel deserialize(String s, byte[] bytes) {
        return objectMapper.readValue(bytes, Hostel.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        this.close();
    }
}
```

and in the properties:

```
spring:
    kafka:
        consumer:
          bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
          group-id: group_id
          topics: test
          key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
          value-serializer: com.kafka.config.HostelSerializer
```

nervertheless whe I receive a message i have this Error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [java.lang.String] 
to [com.message.Hostel] for GenericMessage [.....}]
```

looking at the log it does not get the values from the properties:

```
2020-04-09 16:41:30,840 INFO  :  gid: trace= span= [main] o.a.k.c.consumer.ConsumerConfig ConsumerConfig values: 
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

Comment: Do you have  `spring:` element before the `kafka:`? The INFO log emitting the `ConsumerConfig` should show the applied properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mix de/serialization. Since you configure the **consumer**, you need to use only proper **deserialization** interfaces and implementations:

```
kafka:
consumer:
  bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
  group-id: group_id
  topics: test
  key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
  value-deserializer: com.kafka.config.HostelDeserializer
```

... and ...

```
public class HostelDeserializer implements Deserializer<Hostel> { .. }
```

Comment: Boot should automatically wire in the `value-serializer` property into its auto-configured consumer factory.

Comment: @GaryRussell: My mistake. I have noticed the OP confuses serialization and deserialization.